# Calling secure ServiceStack service from within

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

My main service is decorated with the `[Authenticate]` attribute so any connection attempts (that's important) require clients authentication.

```
[Authenticate]
public class ServerEventsService : Service
{
...
}
```

Is there any way to call services methods from within the server (like in self\web host classes) AND bypass the authentication? There is no `[AllowAnonymous]` thing in ServiceStack as far as I know. If there is no way to bypass the authentication process - how can I authenticate such requests? Is the only way here is to create another ServiceClient in my server host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can call ServiceStack Services directly like any other dependency by resolving it from the IOC and calling it directly with:

```
using var service = base.ResolveService<ServerEventsService>();
var response = service.Post(new Request { ... });
```

Although for improved decoupling it's recommended to use the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway):

```
var response = Gateway.Send(new Request { ... });
```

Also related, see docs on being able to [impersonate users for Internal Requests](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#in-process-authenticated-requests) without requiring the users password.

Comment: So my service will internally post to itself and Authenticate this user?

Comment: @HardLuck no it's just calling the Service directly by-passing Authentication. Only the [link below](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#in-process-authenticated-requests) shows how to impersonate a user, but only works for `CredentialsAuthProvider` which needs to be configured with `SkipPasswordVerificationForInProcessRequests`

Comment: Is there a way to force Authentication even for internal requests? It looks like any internal request is served w\o [Authenticate] filter participation, so any method can be called internally despite the Authenticate and Restrict filters

Comment: @HardLuck no internal requests do not execute request filters, they're called directly.

Comment: Thank you, that's all i need to know